# Silverlight - round doubles away from zero

Tags: silverlight, math

In Silverlight the Math.Round() method does not contain an overload with 'MidpointRounding' parameter. What is the best approach to round a double away from zero in Silverlight in this case?

Example:

Math.Round(1.4) => 1

Math.Round(1.5) => 2

Math.Round(1.6) => 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any number of "hacks" will do it, for example:

```
Public Shared Function SpecialRound(ByVal inVal) As Double
    if (inVal < 0)
        Return Math.Ceil(inVal-0.5)
    Return Math.Floor(inVal+0.5)
End Function
```

I do not know of a "good" way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public double RoundCorrect(double d, int decimals)
{
    double multiplier = Math.Pow(10, decimals);

    if (d < 0)
        multiplier *= -1;

    return Math.Floor((d * multiplier) + 0.5) / multiplier;

}
```

For the examples including how to use this as an extension see the post: [.NET and Silverlight Rounding](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2011/11/10/NET-and-Silverlight-Rounding.aspx)